# Unity Editor positioning/snapping issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor, drag

Basically, unity Editor started to "snap" X position of the transform by 1.
When I drag any object on scene in editor (not in play mode) it slides smoothly along Y axes but dragging it along the X axis causes it to round the value to integer value.

See the the attached GIF:
[image]

I do not hold Command or V buttons, I tried to play with Snap settings (actually, it looks like Snapping is broken at all, because holding Command or V doesn't seem to affect dragging in any way).
If somebody knows, how to fix it in an existing project. I used to face this problem in earlier versions of Unity. Transferring assets to another project helped but this doesn't keep project settings like layers and tags and I'd like to avoid full reimport.

Comment: Not really an answer, but if it works in another project, then you can copy over the old project's settings (including tags and layers) . Just go into the "Library" folder of your old project (It's at the same level as your Assets folder), and copy the "ProjectSettings.asset", "TagManager.asset" etc into your new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem.

I used **Negative X-scale** on one of the parent Transforms.

I wanted to invert the scene. Looks like Unity Editor doesn't like this :)